# Namespacing controllers within routes file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a package which uses controllers from a certain namespace

```php
Route::get('login', 'Full\Name\Space\Login\LoginController@method');
Route::get('other', 'Full\Name\Space\Other\OtherController@method');
```

Is there a 'Laravel' way to define the namespace once at the top of the routes file so I can shorten these controller paths? Something like

```php
use 'Full\Name\Space';

Route::get('login', 'Login\LoginController@method');
Route::get('other', 'Other\OtherController@method');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse you can:

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'foo/1/2'],function(){
    Route::get('specify_your_route', 'BarController@index')
});
```

Route will stay as "specify_your_route", but instead of `\Base\Controller\Namespace\BarController` router will use `\foo\1\2\BarController`

Comment: namespace parameter is applied to controller class, not to the route. Route will stay as "specify_your_route", but instead of \Base\Controller\Namespace\BarController router will use \Base\Controller\Namespace\foo\1\2\BarController

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo big thanks, pointing out my silly mistake. I've updated my answer with yours.

Comment: Again, it's not all, as it still uses the base controller namespace and then appends the value of namespace parameter. OP wants to specify the fully qualified namespace in routing - $namespace attribute of RouteServiceProvider needs to be set to empty string to achieve that. Or it can be set to \Full\Name\Space if all controllers are stored there.